# Session value not update after redirect the page

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have a form, when i submit that form it post to another page, on that page i will set value of post in session, on that time session show current value which is right, after executing the script, it will submit to another third arty tool, the response of this third party tool going to another page which is belong to our app, at that time session display past value, when I load or refresh the page, then it shows current value? I am stuck there, don't know why it's happening and what is the solution of that, I research lot but didn't get any success? if some one help me, I would be very thank full to him.

The third party response is in post the code of that page is

```
     if (isset($_POST)){
      var_debug($_SESSION['reservation']);
      exit();
     }
```

on that script it shows past values, when I refresh or reload the page then it shows current session value

Comment: Post some relevant code please.

Comment: Are you saying that you are only seeing updated values after refreshing the page?

Comment: "Hey, my car is broken, can you fix it?" - "Sure, can i see it?" - "No you cant, i expect that you know the error is without seeing anything."

Comment: @jay your are right... that's the problem

Comment: @user2046638 Ok from what i can guess from this, values from the 3rd party tool are being set to session after ur script has executed or some point after you are checking, so thats y u are seeing this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can provide a code snippet? Or maybe make your question a bit clearer (about the third party tool). Or maybe you can check this http://prajapatinilesh.wordpress.com/2007/09/14/how-to-solve-php-session-problem/
Hope this works!